# Why do I get 403 Forbidden with Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

If I do the response with curl the API works:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => config('healy.loginServerHost') . '/token',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=mytoken&app_version=1.0',
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => config('healy.loginServerUsername') . ':' . config('healy.loginServerPassword'),
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

And I get a 200 response.
However, when I try to use the same with GuzzleClient 6 I get 403 Forbidden response.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post(config('healy.loginServerHost') . '/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grand_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'mytoken',
        'app_version' => 1.0,
    ],
    'http_errors' => false,
    'auth' => [
        config('healy.loginServerUsername'),
        config('healy.loginServerPassword'),
    ],
    'options' => [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    ],
]);
```

What am I missing in Guzzle? Are these calls not identical?

Comment: What HTTP authentication type does the target use? cURL on its own tries several different methods. Guzzle tries only the one specified, or `Basic` as the default. If the target uses Digest auth, then specify that as third parameter in your auth array, `'digest'`

Comment: @CBroe target uses Basic Auth

Comment: Sure that `app_version` is set correctly then? In your first code, you had that hard-coded, now you are trying to read it from the config settings.

Comment: Have you checked what the response _body_ contains, when you get the 403 response? Often there’s a human-readable error explanation in there.

Comment: @CBroe yes its the same. I also tried to hardcode it in Guzzle but same issue. Only human readable error explanation is  
-reasonPhrase: "Forbidden"
  -statusCode: 403

Comment: there is no options request_option in guzzle.

Comment: I am not using `request_option` anywhere?

Comment: [request-options in guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#request-options)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `options` request_option, we use options with asynchronous requests when using the class `GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler`. Use `curl` request_option instead.

```
 $client = new Client([
    'curl' => [
            \CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            \CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            \CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            \CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            \CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            \CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        ]
    ]);
    
    $response = $client->post(config('healy.loginServerHost') . '/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grand_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => 'mytoken',
            'app_version' => 1.0,
        ],
        'http_errors' => false,
        'auth' => [
            config('healy.loginServerUsername'),
            config('healy.loginServerPassword'),
        ]
    ]);
```

You can use curl request option within the request as well, as a third parameter to the option array.

But I would suggest If you are using guzzle then you should use it completely.
So, you can replace the curl option with a lot of request options the guzzle provides.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['curl' => [\CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true]]);

$response = $client->post(config('healy.loginServerHost') . '/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grand_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'mytoken',
        'app_version' => 1.0,
    ],
    'http_errors' => false,
    'auth' => [
        config('healy.loginServerUsername'),
        config('healy.loginServerPassword'),
    ],
    'allow_redirects' => [
        'max'             => 10,        // allow at most 10 redirects.
        'strict'          => true,      // use "strict" RFC compliant redirects.
        // 'referer'         => true,      // add a Referer header
        'protocols'       => ['https'], // only allow https URLs
        // 'on_redirect'     => $onRedirect,
        'track_redirects' => true
    ],
    'version' => 1.1 // equivalent to CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    // No need of \CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0, as it is by default 0, if want any other value then use timeout request options
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with this can add user-agent header -

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'headers' => [
            'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        ]
    ]);

// Request code will continue here
```

Hope this will solve the problem